# Stream Analytics job execution order

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics

In a stream analytics job we have something like this:

select *
into output1
from eventhub

select *
into output2
from eventhub

If I have the query setup like above does output1 always get executed first?  Or is there a way to make sure output1 always get executed first?  Will having two separate jobs help?

The reason for this question is output1 outputs data to tablestorage and output2 reads from tablestorage.

Comment: Stream Analytics executes standing queries. For the query you shared, both will be executed simultaneously. Can you please describe your scenario better? What do you mean by output1 executed first and why is it needed?

Comment: if there is a dependency between two steps you should have two jobs where 1st job takes data from your original source and send it to output which will be input for second job. if no dependency order shouldn't matter. Could you please provide more details around your goal.

Comment: Yes there is a dependency between the two.  I have updated the original post.  SA can output directly to tablestorage and thats what the query for output1 is doing.  I felt that it is inefficient to first output to a queue and have a job send data to tablestorage and from the job send to another queue(for output2) but maybe thats the only way?

Comment: Output1 is table storage, what is output2? Also, what is the dependency between output1 and output2 that requires one to be executed before the other?

Answer (score 0):

Both queries are executed in parallel. So answering your question - no.
You can have two jobs where first output will be the input of another one.

But probably it will be better to use something different e.g.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable-functions-overview

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  Looks like something useful!